# Accessing a function from another file (under the same project) in google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

So I have two files ImgurAPI.gs and OAuth2.gs and I'm trying to call a function from OAuth2.gs in ImgurAPI.gs (or use a variable either works). I was under the impression that I could just call the function from this post:

[Call functions from another "class" / file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335646/call-functions-from-another-class-file)

However, I get the following error

```
ReferenceError: getImgurService is not defined
```

Here's my code

**OAuth2.gs**

```
function getImgurService(){
...}
```

**ImgurAPI.gs**

```
var imgurService = getImgurService(); ...
```

So how am I supposed to call a function from another file?

Comment: In your situation, is this thread useful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/67681954